# Programmatically get login URL of a connected app

Tags: metadata-api, connected-apps

I am reluctant to hard code or use custom setting (it's too long) for a login URL of a community.

I see there are ways to access metadata API to get certain details, but was wondering is there a dedicated function to get login URL for the connected app?

If now, what is the best approach here?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a dedicated custom object (which won't have the 255 char limit for text fields) to store the endpoint.

Comment: I managed to find a query-able root URL in AuthConfig object. Another option is storing callback URL and consumer key in custom settings and concatenating actual final login URL using Apex.